# Send JSONArray Data to MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have a JSONArray, retrieving from Android local SQLite database, which I want to send to MySQL database. The JSONArray structure is as following

```
[
    {
        "value1": "1518518041",
        "value2": "90.390342",
        "value3": "23.7758309"
    },
    {
        "value1": "1518518071",
        "value2": "90.3903512",
        "value3": "23.7758192"
    },
    {
        "value1": "1518518200",
        "value2": "90.390342",
        "value3": "23.7758309"
    },
    ....
]
```

Now I am trying to send the data to MySQL using Volley `JsonArrayRequest` here is the code

```
JSONArray jsonArray  = db.getResults();
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonArrayRequest sendSqliteData = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonArray,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            params.put("value1", jsonArray.getString("value1"));
            params.put("value2", jsonArray.getString("value2"));
            params.put("value3", jsonArray.getString("value3"));                
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }
};;
queue.add(sendSqliteData);
```

Here is the php script

```
<?php
// connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($link, "myDatabase");

// get the JSONArray the app sends
$contents = file_get_contents('php://input');

$jsonArray = json_decode($contents, true);
$jsonCount = count($jsonArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonCount; $i++) {
    $item = $jsonArray[$i];
    $value1 = utf8_decode($item['value1']);
    $value2 = utf8_decode($item['value2']);
    $value3 = utf8_decode($item['value3']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO dataTable VALUES('$value1', '$value2', '$value3')";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
}
```

Where I am doing wrong? Why the data is not writing in MySQL table?

**EDIT:**
The problem I am getting in the Try/Catch block.

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            params.put("value1", jsonArray.getString("value1"));
            params.put("value2", jsonArray.getString("value2"));
            params.put("value3", jsonArray.getString("value3"));                
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return params;
    }
```

In the Try/Catch block I am retrieving String from the `jsonArray` whereas I am requesting volley to make a JsonArray post. My problem is I have data already in `jsonArray` variable in the format given upper JSON sample. How can I send that JSON to server using PHP. I am trying with this code but its not working. Please suggest me or edit the given code to do it properly.

Comment: Does `dataTable` contains only 3 columns?

Comment: You have SQL injection in your PHP code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: echo what is happening inside your PHP script. Is it receiving the data, is your JsonCount greater than zero? Your Mysql query may not even being called.

Comment: `JsonArrayRequest sendSqliteData = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonArray,`  where did you define URL variable?

Comment: did you used `org.json.JSONArray` ? if yes then `JSONArray` don't have any `getString` method that takes `String` as parameter

Comment: Thanks all for commenting. I have updated my question and tried to clear the problem again. Syscall, no problem with dataTable. Raymond, I have defined URL variable earlier. @AbuYousuf , Yes your indication was right, can you give me a solution how to do that? Steve, JsonCount is greater than zero and the problem probably not in PHP code, its in Java Code.